# Why can’t prove two vectors to be collinear if the vectors have difference signs using guess?

Tags: vectors

Vectors are $A = xi + 2j + zk$ and $B = 2i + yj + 1k$

Question is to check if they ($A$ and $B$) are parallel or collinear.

So, in my book it says that $x= 2 , y = 2$ and $z = 1$. Then they are parallel. That looks pretty obvious too.

Now, for another $Q$ with negative values.
$A = 2i + 3j -4k$ and $B = 3i-aj +bk$.

Now, here they didn’t assume $a = -3$ and $b = 4$. But, solved by another method i.e. that their ratio of coefficients should be equal.

$\frac{2}{ 3} $= $\frac {3}{-a}$= $\frac 
{-4}{b}$. So,

$b \times 2 = -4 \times 3$ , $b = -6$. Now, here the values were solved in a different way and have different answers. Why is that ? I think due to negative sign but for the 1st $Q$. I am not sure.

$\frac{x}{2} = \frac{2}{y} =\frac{z}{1}$ . Here, we can’t solve it the way we did 2nd $Q$. Since there are 3 variables . Then, how to solve this

Comment: Firstly, it would be nice if you type your Math expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). That would increase the readability of those expressions. Second of all, it is a bit ambiguous what is the exact question. Is it "determine the unknown values $x$, $y$ and $z$ if the vectors are colinear"?

Comment: @KenHung No , I have edited it. Please check again if you get it. It is much more simpler words now and clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not requested to check that the vectors are parallel. You are asked to find values of the unknowns that make them so.

1. $$\frac{x}{2}=\frac{2}{y}=\frac{z}{1}.$$ For convenience, you can assume that the common ratio is $1$.
2. $$\frac{2}{3}=\frac{3}{-a}=\frac{-4}{b}.$$ Here the common ratio is $\dfrac23$, giving $a=-\dfrac92,b=-6$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, we could also have written that $A$ and $B$ are parallel if $\frac{x}{2}=\frac{2}{y}=\frac{z}{1}$. By taking the given particular vectors, we can make $A$ a scalar multiple of $B$. It has $3$ variables, so cannot be directly solved. But, you may use trial and error to find appropriate values.  
In the second case, if we write $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{3}{-a}=\frac{-4}{b}$, and compare $2$nd and $3$rd term with the first one, we get $a=-\frac{9}{2}$ and $b=-6$. The first case was direct, probably that's why it was not explicitly stated.